# SQL Server ALTER datetime to datetime2 does not work

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to convert a "datetime" variable to "datetime2" format.

```
# Load libraries
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame("myid" = stringi::stri_rand_strings(5, 5),
                 "mydate" = c(Sys.time(), Sys.time()-1, Sys.time()-2, Sys.time()-3, Sys.time()-4) )

# Create SQL table sschema.ttable
DBI::dbWriteTable(conn = connection,
                  name = DBI::Id(schema = "sschema", table = "ttable"),
                  value = df,
                  overwrite = TRUE,
                  append = FALSE)

# Query for variable type in the SQL table
query <- paste0("exec sp_columns ", "ttable")
query <- DBI::dbSendQuery(connection, query)
res <- NULL
res <- DBI::dbFetch(query)
DBI::dbClearResult(query)
view(res)

# Alter mydate to datetime2
query <- DBI::dbSendStatement(conn = connection,
                              statement = paste0("ALTER TABLE sschema.ttable ALTER COLUMN mydate datetime2"))
DBI::dbFetch(query)
DBI::dbClearResult(query)
```

but this leads to the error

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1617: 00000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'ttable', database 'dbo', schema 'sschema'.
>  'ALTER TABLE sschema.ttablename ALTER COLUMN mydate datetime2'

However, converting another `VARCHAR(10)` variable in the same table to `VARCHAR(100)` works fine. Any idea what is the problem? How to get this working?

I am working with Microsoft SQL Azure version 12, by operating on an RStudio-server and the DBI library.

Comment: Q1: What database compatibility level is your database at? 
Q2: Can you create a new table (even a temp table) with a `DATETIME2` column?

Comment: The error appears to be telling you the problem; you don't have the permissions to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @RossPresser for the input. Q1 The Native Compatibility Level should be 110. Q2 Yes, I am able to create a table with a datetime2-formated variable!

Comment: Thanks @Larnu but I suspect that might not be the reason as I can alter a variable of type VARCHAR(10) to VARCHAR(100) but not datetime to datetime2. Both variables are in the same table.

Or is it possible that the server (and not user permissions) prevents changing datetime to datetime2?

Comment: You're  not updating the values when you change from a `varchar(10)` to a `varchar(100)` though, @obruzzi .

Comment: Please provide full R code block and error message. This does not read right as an `ALTER` statement raises an `UPDATE` error. Which command are you actually running? And if you can, please do not generalize schema/table/column names but use actual names. Maybe [reserved words](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) are being used.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, you are right. Please find a better reprex. No UPDATE command is used.

Answer (score 1):

To change the data type of a column you must have both the ALTER permission and UPDATE permission on the table.

From the docs:

> Adding a column that updates the rows of the table requires UPDATE permission on the table.

[ALTER TABLE - permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions)

This goes for ALTERing an existing column too, as you can verify like this:

```
use tempdb
go
revert 
go
if exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = 'fred')
  drop user fred
go
drop table if exists tablename
go
create user fred without login

create table tablename(id int, variablename varchar(20))
go
grant select on tablename to fred 
--grant update on tablename to fred  --uncomment to clear error
grant alter on schema::dbo to fred

execute as user='fred'
  ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ALTER COLUMN variablename datetime2
revert
```

Comment: Thanks @David Browne for the input. So if I use ALTER (while in fact I am updating a variable), it will work, but if really need to alter (datetime --> datetime2), it fails due to insufficient permissions? The SQL server and permissions are managed by our admin. I will need to ask for ALTER permissions. I will confirm if this works, but this seems to be the solution.

Comment: You need ALTER _and_ UPDATE on the table to perform this operation.  Or just ask your admin to run the ALTER TABLE statement for you.